# How to effectively deal with uncompressed saves during package check?

Tags: r, package-development

In recent efforts to develop a package, I'm including datasets in the `data/` folder of my package. In my specific case I have 5 datasets all of which are in `data.table` format (although the issues I describe below persist if I keep them as `data.frame`). I've saved each one as individual `.rda` files and documented them appropriately.

When I run `check()` from package `devtools`, I get the following warnings:

```
 checking data for ASCII and uncompressed saves ... WARNING
  Warning: large data file(s) saved inefficiently:
          size ASCII compress
  data1.rda 129Kb  TRUE     gzip
  data2.rda 101Kb  TRUE     gzip
  data3.rda 1.6Mb  TRUE     gzip

  Note: significantly better compression could be obtained
        by using R CMD build --resave-data
              old_size new_size compress
  data1.rda         129Kb     34Kb       xz
  data2.rda         101Kb     20Kb       xz
  data4.rda          92Kb     35Kb       xz
  data3.rda         1.6Mb    116Kb       xz
  species.rda     12Kb      9Kb       xz
```

I've tried saving the data with `resaveRdaFiles` (package `tools`) with the recommended `xz` compression. Even after doing that, the warning persists.

OK, so I run `R CMD build --resave-data` and the warning continues to persist.

What am I missing here and how do I overcome this issue (now and in the future)?

Comment: Could you try changing the compression options (see `compress` or `compression_level`) when you save the original RDA file? Perhaps resaveRdaFiles() does that properly? I'm not familiar with the function...

Comment: Did you try saveRDS (.rds file) instead...more info here http://ucfagls.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/saving-and-loading-r-objects/

Comment: Yep, tried `saveRDS()` and it does not save any space and you cannot run `resaveRdaFile()` on those to compress further.

Comment: A package I wrote a couple of years back suddenly started producing this warning around when R 2.15 was being developed. In my case, the problem was that I'd made my .Rdata files back in version 2.9, and that format was deprecated.  Manually re-saving the files with a recent R version seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 33):

When you save your `.rda` file, please use the command: `save(..., file='test.rda', compress='xz')`
This will help to solve the problem!

Comment: To (perhaps) clarify this point, I found something like `package.skeleton(name="mypackage")` followed by `save(test, file="mypackage/data/test.rda", compress='xz')` worked.